# how jwt token be verified if it's valid

Tags: jwt, token

suppose, I just generate one token from keycloak and if I use this token to any web site which require a token to login, how those web sites know that is not valid token. because I can't see jwt token contain some credential info in it.

I want to know how token is used to login.

Comment: You could use an online debugger like [this](https://jwt.io/) or even better install a client which prints what's inside the token.

Comment: When you are generating a jwt you are using a secret. when the server is getting the jwt it will use the secret in order to vaildate the token, if the secret doesnt match it will throw an error. also some servers are having the jwt stored in the db . when the server gets the token it will try to find it in the db, if not found it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JWT token contains a signature, which is used to confirm the authenticity of the payload (including claims about user name, roles etc.) of the token.

This signature is created either:

- By a *private-public key pair* a.k.a. asymmetric cryptography. The creator has the private key. Validating servers have access to the public key. Signing and validation are done using RSA or ECDSA algorithms.
- By a *shared secret* which both the creator and the validating server have. Signing and validation are done using a HMAC algorithm.

See https://jwt.io/introduction for a quick introduction to JSON Web Tokens

Comment: Thanks nail, this answer is what I was looking for. : -)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a token to validate a sign-in of a user, you will have all control of revalidate time and will search every request to validate this token. When it's a token from another site or provider, you will send a request to this provider requesting this validation, and you will receive a token to store in your backend and another to use on the client side. This token on the client side you will use like an indentifier, and when you decide to revalidate this indentifier, you will use the token stored in your backend to send to this other provider. This is basically what we can call `OAuth`.